# how to monitor process in Mac

Tags: macos, monitoring

I have a software that runs on mac (using terminal program) the program is old software that talks to phone using blue-tooth. The pairing sometimes breaks and I have to restart it to work again. Is there a way to monitor the process and make it run again automatically??

Thanks,

Tam

Comment: you are looking to develop software to see if an outgoing connection is somehow severed so you can automatically reestablish connection with a remote service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "monitor" you mean "monitor for the process dying," then you should look at [launchd](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Articles/LaunchOnDemandDaemons.html), which can automatically restart a process when it dies. Or do you have some other monitoring in mind?